# How to make sort arrow visible for initial data?

Tags: ng-grid

I have a grid that has data available initially and the data is already sorted by the first column (Date). I'd like to have the sort arrow present on that column showing that that is the current sorting.

I've set the sortInfo option but it doesn't rflect in the UI.

Is there a way to get the sort arrow to show for initial data without someone having to click on the column headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the *sortInfo* to *asc* or *desc* the sort arrows should already show.
Tested and works for me when I specify this in my gridOptions

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        sortInfo: {fields:['name'], directions:['asc'] }
 };
```

A small side note, I had to specify the directions as lowercase or sorting failed...
It's also very important to set the sort direction, as that is where the ngGrid code looks at (see also  [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/ng-grid-2.0.7.debug.js) at lines 796-801):

```
self.showSortButtonUp = function() {
    return self.sortable ? self.sortDirection === DESC : self.sortable;
};
self.showSortButtonDown = function() {
    return self.sortable ? self.sortDirection === ASC : self.sortable;
};
```

Comment: You're right. I have  written "Desc" and it needs to be all lowercase as you said.